# Unable to boot from Windows Vista DVD on Dell Inspiron 1525 laptop

Tags: ubuntu, boot, windows-vista, dvd, dell-inspiron

My Dell Inspiron 1525 laptop doesn't boot from Windows Vista Reinstallation DVD provided by Dell itself.

This is an old laptop and I plan to resell it. So I boot from an Ubuntu LiveUSB and do a full and slow NTFS format of the internal HardDrive. Now I want to install Windows Vista from the Reinstallation DVD before I put it up for sale. But it doesn't boot from the DVD. It throws the below error

```
error: no such partition.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

Please help me fix this issue.

notes:
1. I can boot from Ubuntu Live USB
2. The reinstallation DVD is readable on the same laptop after booting to Ubuntu Live USB.

**Solution**:
Not sure what exactly solved the problem. The boot order is important as suggested by @dws. But I had already set the boot order correctly. What worked for me is that I removed all partitions from HDD so I basically had an unformatted disk. And then laptop accepted the Windows DVD for booting. Was their grub hiding in the HDD and interfering with the boot process? i dont know.

Answer (score 1):

Adjusting your BIOS settings is probably going to fix this.  Try to get into your BIOS before it goes to the grub rescue prompt by mashing f8 or DEL or f2 or maybe f12 (depends on your machine) after you reboot.

It may take a couple tries, just keep restarting/mashing until you get in there.

Then look for something along the lines of "boot priority" and move your DVD drive to the top of the list.  Hit f10 to save and exit and BIOS should pass control to your Vista disk.